# React Material UI Slider to change Border Radius

Tags: css, reactjs, button, material-ui, slider

Using React Material UI's [slider]:(https://material-ui.com/components/slider/#slider)and [button]:(https://material-ui.com/api/button/).

The goal is to change the border radius of the button with the slider but struggling to grab the value variable and to figure out a way to apply it to the Button component.

I am brain dead due to trial and error. Can someone help me out or give me good advice?

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import Slider from "@material-ui/core/Slider";
import Input from "@material-ui/core/Input";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    "& > *": {
      margin: theme.spacing(1)
    }
  },
  Button: {
    width: 150,
    height: 50,
    borderRadius: "var(--borderRadius)"
  }
}));
export default function InputSlider() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(30);
  const handleSliderChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };
  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    setValue(event.target.value === "" ? "" : Number(event.target.value));
  };
  const handleBlur = () => {
    if (value < 0) {
      setValue(0);
    } else if (value > 100) {
      setValue(100);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <style>
        {`:root {
          --borderRadius = ${value}px;
        }`}
      </style>
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        color="primary"
        value="value"
        onChange={handleSliderChange}
        className={classes.Button}
      >
        Fire laser
      </Button>
      <Grid container spacing={2}>
        <Grid item xs>
          <Slider
            value={typeof value === "number" ? value : 0}
            onChange={handleSliderChange}
            aria-labelledby="input-slider"
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item>
          <Input
            value={value}
            margin="dense"
            onChange={handleInputChange}
            onBlur={handleBlur}
            inputProps={{
              step: 10,
              min: 0,
              max: 24,
              type: "number"
            }}
          />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here the work in a [sandbox]: (https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-nm2qw?file=/demo.js:0-1878)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the `borderRadius` of a `Button` using the `style` prop.

Just add this to your `Button`,

```
style={{ borderRadius: value }}
```

Check this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-tqnbw) for working example.

[image]

Comment: https://media2.giphy.com/media/26gsjCZpPolPr3sBy/giphy.gif?cid=ecf05e47o3h5slrlm4fq0z0gnwkkzn5o3jr1yjiz324uceqh&rid=giphy.gif&ct=g

Comment: Glad to have helped :) Please consider accepting the answer as well. thanks.